# How I obtain values from another row to place in the current row in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(
    [
    ['TAVG',51,'2020-01-01'],
    ['TMAX',59,'2020-01-01'],
    ['TMIN',46,'2020-01-01'],
    ['TAVG',53,'2020-01-02'],
    ['TMAX',61,'2020-01-02'],
    ['TMIN',45,'2020-01-02'],
    ['TAVG',50,'2020-01-03'],
    ['TMAX',60,'2020-01-03'],
    ['TMIN',40,'2020-01-03']
    ],
    columns = ['datatype', 'value', 'date']
)
```

[image]

I would like to combine the values for each date in a single row like this:

[image]

I've made various attempts using `loc` but I failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pivot`

```
out = df_test.pivot('date','datatype','value').reset_index()
Out[88]: 
datatype    TAVG  TMAX  TMIN
date                        
2020-01-01    51    59    46
2020-01-02    53    61    45
2020-01-03    50    60    40
```

Comment: Thanks - that worked perfectly. Do you know how I can remove the `datatype` heading? I tried renaming but that didn't work: https://i.imgur.com/0T7j5l2.png

Comment: `out =out.rename_axis(None,axis=1)` @IamWarmduscher

Answer (score 1):

```
df_test.set_index(['date','datatype'])['value'].unstack().reset_index()
```

d

```
atatype        date  TAVG  TMAX  TMIN
0         2020-01-01    51    59    46
1         2020-01-02    53    61    45
2         2020-01-03    50    60    40
```